# Prove picking cards from a deck has a solution

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Original question is: Shuffle a deck and divide it into 13 equal piles, each 4. Prove there exist a solution, such that we can pick a card from each pile, and totally the 13 picked out cards are exactly Ace to K, regardless of suits.

What I think of this question is a deck consists of $n$ ranks and $m$ suits, divide into $n$ equal piles, each $m$. Prove there exist:

(a) a solution; (b) $m$ solutions; (c) $m^n$ solutions(should be wrong); (d) somewhere between (a)(b)(c)

NOTE: this is a **graph theory** final exam question. I wonder did I miss something when taking this course.

Comment: Do you remember Hall's marriage theorem?

Comment: @MikeEarnest It rings a bell somehow, but I did not quite comprehend the meaning of it(and its variations), so I could not see the link between this example and this theorem. Forgive my stupidity. I did this theorem for matching in bipartite.

Comment: @MikeEarnest AHHH I SEE, It is finding a matching between these 13 piles and A to K.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I also remember that this theorem is a TONCAS, but just couldn't think of it having link with this example when doing exam... Still I wonder if the enhanced conclusion is true.

Comment: For the enhancement, use [the Marshall Hall Jr extension of Hall's Marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem#Marshall_Hall_Jr._variant).

Comment: does permuting a pile of 4 (or $m$) count as a unique solution?

Comment: if it counts as an unique one, then by some inequalities and elementary combinatorics one can show there are more than $m^n$ solutions